# An example of a henselian valuation of rank 2.

Tags: commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

I need to know simple examples of valuations of rank bigger than one. Please help me to concrete some examples of valuations of rank bigger than one with their valuation rings (specially henselian valuations of rank bigger than one with their valuation rings).
Thank you for your answers